# custom colors with tailwind.css and string interpolation, react app with api

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying set a custom background color with hex ie: `color`=#a8f07a

This isn't this working, why??

```js
  <p className={`bg-[${color}]`}>hello message</p>
```

This does work (but I prefer tailwinds classes)

```js
  <p style={{ background: `${color}` }} >hello message</p>
```

Comment: Yea....looks like there's no way to do it with TW classes.

Comment: There are but you have to safelist every color you need in which I see no point

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to make sure that your class is not purged by your compiler.
In order to do so you must safelist those colors.
Here is an example to safelist all values from 1 to 100 for the "top" attribute:

```
//in your talwind.config.js      
safelist: [
        ...[...Array(100).keys()].flatMap(i => [`top-[${i}%]`),
    ],
```

You could also safelist colors by hand with one entry per color.
I suggest finding a way to generate all the colors codes then to safelist them following this example.

Here is the link to the documentations regarding safelisting:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes